Keep process invisible for user in linux dialog script
I got a project with a dialog script, where the TUI will run and the admin can handle passwords.
My problem is that when admin presses changepass for example, i want it to run the command for changing password, but the process in the terminal pops up for a second on the screen.
I dont want the terminal to show when it executes things. I have tried to add the & and > /dev/null 2>&1, but nothing really works.
I have tried running the specific commands with the  & and with > /dev/null but without improvement.
This is the script i want it to run without popping up when user have pressed on change password and have entered old pass, new pass and current pass:
expect <<EOF 
spawn wdpass -c 
expect "Insert the OLD password"
send "$curr_password\r"
expect "Insert the NEW password"
send "$new_password\r"
expect "Confirm the NEW password"
send "$confirm_password\r"
expect eof
EOF


Re "I have tried running the specific commands": Please provide those commands (the code) you want help with.

please use a [repro].

hey, have edited my post now

Possible duplicate of: How to suppress expect send output?

"the process in the terminal pops up for a second" -- what exactly is displayed?

the problem was that it displayed the process of changing the password trough the terminal, but i didnt want the user to be able to see it. But i solved it!

I solved the problem by setting the expect script inside () and adding > /dev/null & after.
( expect <<EOF
spawn wdpass -c
expect "Insert the OLD password"
sleep 0.1
send "$curr_password\r"
expect "Insert the NEW password"
sleep 0.1
send "$new_password\r"
expect "Confirm the NEW password"
sleep 0.1
send "$confirm_password\r"
expect eof
EOF
) > /dev/null &

